# ¿Cómo actualizar a Python 3 desde el terminal en Mac?

Tags: python, macos

¿Existe un método que permita utilizar versiones mas recientes de Python sin que causen conflictos con la versión instalada en el sistema?

La versión que obtengo en la terminal es la siguiente:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb  6 2017, 23:53:20) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

¿Es conviente actualizar la versión del sistema? ¿Cómo puedo usar otras versiones de Python además de la `2.7.10`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El Python del sistema [Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb  6 2017, 23:53:20)], que en macOS Sierra (versión actual 10.12.4) **no debes actualizarlo**. Muchas cosas dependen de él y tu sistema podría quedar inutilizado.

Tienes dos opciones:

### Homebrew

[Homebrew](https://brew.sh/index_es.html) es un gestor de paquetes que te permite instalar muchos paquetes, incluyendo Python, de forma local, sin interferir con las versiones del sistema. Si ya tienes instalado Homebrew, solo tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

```
$ brew update && brew install python
```

Si no has instalado Homebrew, sigue las instrucciones en su página principal.

### Pyenv

[Pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) es un gestor de versiones de Python. Te permite instalar diferentes versiones de Python y usar la que te convenga sin que interfiera con las demás.

Personalmente te recomiendo usar el [**instalador**](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer) que incluye una versión especial de `virtualenv`.

#### Como se usa Pyenv

Digamos que tienes un proyecto que se llama `cmi`, ubicado en `~/proyectos/cmi/` que usa la versión 2.7 de Python. Solo tienes que crear el entorno con el siguiente comando:

```
$ pyenv install 2.7.13
$ pyenv rehash   # para activar la nueva versión
$ pyenv virtualenv 2.7.13 cmi
```

Y a continuación, **en el directorio de tu proyecto**, escribes lo siguiente:

```
~/proyectos/cmi$ pyenv local cmi
```

De este modo, cuando te cambies a ese directorio, se activará automáticamente el entorno `cmi`.

Si tienes otro proyecto, en `~/proyectos/sgc` que necesita la versión `4.3.1` de Anaconda, la instalas, creas el entorno virtual y la activas para tu proyecto:

```
~/proyectos/sgc$ pyenv install anaconda3-4.3.1
~/proyectos/sgc$ pyenv rehash   # para activar la nueva versión
~/proyectos/sgc$ pyenv virtualenv anaconda3-4.3.1 sgc
~/proyectos/sgc$ pyenv local sgc
```

Tus entornos de Python son independientes unos de otros, puedes ocupar una versión para hacer cualquier cantidad de entornos virtuales, también independientes, etc.

Para ver todas las versiones disponibles, que son unas 300, ejecuta este comando:

```
$ pyenv install --list
```

### Adenda

Pyenv, al igual que los programas que tienen la misma intención, como `nvm` para Node.js, `rvm` para Ruby y `swiftenv` tienen el mismo objetivo y funcionan de manera parecida en entornos *nix, no solo en macOS, al contrario de `brew` que es exclusivo de este sistema operativo.